# Since which version of NodeJS the new v8 engine is used

Tags: node.js, v8

Since which version of NodeJS the new V8 engine is used? Its said that the new V8 engine has significant improvements to garbage collection and performance.

I'm using `v0.10.35` version of NodeJS & has performance issues, so need to tune few params such as `–max-old-space-size=8192` in order to improve the performance. But, in order to get the said param in effect need to recompile the node as specified [here](http://blog.caustik.com/2012/04/11/escape-the-1-4gb-v8-heap-limit-in-node-js/).

Comment: Why don't you upgrade Node.js itself?

Comment: Upgrading NodeJS itself will take some time as I'm using lot of other libraries, I should upgrade the libraries as well & lot of test-cases to pass. I want to know if I don't need to recompile node after tweaking few params like `-max-old-space-size=8192`.

Comment: As far as I know, you don't have to recompile node. Why don't you try?

Comment: I've done the changes to pass the said command line argument. As per  current monitoring system I don't see much improvement, are there other ways of checking if this param has brought in effect (in NodeJS)?